# Subtraction results in Null when empty SUM in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT (SUM(total) / 100) - 

(SELECT (SUM(other_table.total) / 100) FROM other_table WHERE 1) ) AS total

FROM orders WHERE 1
```

It works as expected if there is at least one row in other_table.

If there are no rows in **other_table** the result is **NULL**.

I know this happens because **(SUM(other_table.total)** gives **NULL** when there is nothing to **SUM**.

My question is: How could I update the query to account for the possibility of having an empty **other_table**

Comment: "this happens because (SUM(other_table.total) gives NULL when there is nothing to SUM." --- `SUM` is not even called there. It actually happens because the whole expression just returns nothing.

Comment: It gets called in the subquery which in turn gets substracted from (SUM(total) / 100)

Comment: Nope, `SUM` is not called because there are no rows returned. So there are no values to apply it for.

Comment: Of course it's right. What is wrong is your statement that it's `SUM()` that returns `NULL`, which it does not, since it's not called.

Comment: Thanks I have already been suggested to use COALESCE to account for the null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72098/discussion-between-helloworld-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` :

```
SELECT (SUM(total) / 100) - 

COALESCE( (SELECT (SUM(other_table.total) / 100) FROM other_table WHERE 1) ,0) AS total

FROM orders WHERE 1
```